# How to get the count of fields that are either None ot empty in a row using ORM Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, orm

I have a model,

```
class personal_profile(models.Model):
    custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(default='pro.png', upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

I want to get the number of field's count which are either None or "".

`personal_profile.objects.get(custom_user=some_user_id)`

By the above query, I can get the queryset of that specific user. Now I want to check all the fields belongs to that custom_user. For example, `picture, desgination. gender, date_of_birth, language, linkedin_url`

Thanks

Comment: Read this https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-filter-for-empty-or-null-values-in-a-django-queryset/#combining-filters

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article, I understood how to use `filter()` and `exclude()`. But I need to know what if I don't want about all the objects, instead I want to know just about the one. For eg., what I want is when I execute the query `personal_profile.objects.get(custom_user=request.user)` I get output that looks like `<QuerySet [<personal_profile: 2>]>` which contains 6 different fields values that is `(picture, desgination. gender, date_of_birth, language, linkedin_url)`. Now I want to know which field among them are empty or Null and returns output like 2 values empty from 6 values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices. You can either do the counting at the python level or the database level.

## Solution #1 Python level

Use the `@property` decorator to count the number of empty fields.

```py
class PersonalProfile(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def empty_fields_count(self):
        fields = ["picture", "desgination", "gender", "date_of_birth", "language", "linkedin_url"]
        empty_values = {"", None}
        empty_values_count = 0

        for field in fields:
            field_value = getattr(self, field)
            if field_value in empty_values:
                empty_values_count += 1
        return empty_values_count
```

And use it like so

```py
personal_profile = PersonalProfile.objects.get(custom_user=some_user_id)
# this will return the number of empty fields
personal_profile.empty_fields_count
```

## Solution #2 Database level

Use `annotate` to sum the number of empty fields

```py
personal_profile_queryset = PersonalProfile.objects.annotate(
    picture_empty=models.Case(
        models.When(models.Q(picture__isnull=True) | models.Q(picture=""), then=1),
        default=0,
    ),
    desgination_empty=models.Case(
        models.When(models.Q(desgination__isnull=True) | models.Q(desgination=""), then=1),
        default=0,
    ),
    gender_empty=models.Case(
        models.When(models.Q(gender__isnull=True) | models.Q(gender=""), then=1),
        default=0,
    ),
    date_of_birth_empty=models.Case(
        models.When(date_of_birth__isnull=True, then=1),
        default=0,
    ),
    language_empty=models.Case(
        models.When(models.Q(language__isnull=True) | models.Q(language=""), then=1),
        default=0,
    ),
    linkedin_url_empty=models.Case(
        models.When(models.Q(linkedin_url__isnull=True) | models.Q(linkedin_url=""), then=1),
        default=0,
    ),
    empty_fields_count=(
        models.F("picture_empty") + 
        models.F("desgination_empty") + 
        models.F("gender_empty") + 
        models.F("date_of_birth_empty") + 
        models.F("language_empty") + 
        models.F("linkedin_url_empty")
    )
)
```

Then use the queryset as follows

```py
personal_profile = personal_profile_queryset.get(custom_user=some_user_id)
# this will return the number of empty fields
personal_profile.empty_fields_count
```

#### Notes

You might want to move the `annotate` codes to be in a custom [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) or [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-1) if you want to reuse the queryset with annotated `empty_fields_count` attribute.

Comment: Thankyou so much!! Works Charm!! Also wants to know which way is more preferable according to you  ?? Python or Database Level ?

Comment: Typically, doing it at the database level will be faster.